# OK response helper returns extra json data to response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

How do I configure ASP.NET Core to not append/add any data to my JSON responses? At the moment it is configured with `services.AddMvc();` in `ConfigureServices` but no custom formatters have been added beyond this.

If I return from my controller method using `Ok()` (or one of the other help methods like `BadRequest`, `NotFound`, `Unauthorized`..) I get the following response.

Code:

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult Foo() 
{
    return Ok(Json(new { Hello = "Hi", OneMoreField = 1234}));
}
```

Response from hitting http://localhost:port/foo

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2017 12:14:11 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "contentType": null,
    "serializerSettings": null,
    "statusCode": null,
    "value": {
        "hello": "Hi",
        "oneMoreField": 1234
    }
}
```

If I remove the `Ok(...)` call and just return `Json(new { Hello = "Hi", OneMoreField = 1234})` I get what I expect, an object like this

```
"value": {
    "hello": "Hi",
    "oneMoreField": 1234
}
```

What am I missing, is the a debug flag or something I have not toggled correctly?

Comment: Why do you want to add "OK()" if you get expected result without it?

Answer (score 5):

You are not missing anything, but you are certainly doing extra work. The `Json` helper function is the same as using `Ok` but forcing the response to be in JSON format. When you do `Ok(Json(data))` you are serializing the `JsonResult` rather than `data`.

So, use either:

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult Foo() 
{
    return Json(new { Hello = "Hi", OneMoreField = 1234});
}
```

Or:

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult Foo() 
{
    return Ok(new { Hello = "Hi", OneMoreField = 1234});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Controller` class method `Json(object data)`.

```
public IActionResult Foo() {
     return Json(new { Hello = "Hi", OneMoreField = 1234});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, add dataType property after Content-Type and set it to json:

```
dataType: "json",
```